# How to get `this' from a passed method

Tags: haxe

If one pass a method as a funarg, how one can tell if passed function is a method, and get `this' object of a method is?

```
class A {
    public function f():Void{
        trace("f");
    }
}

class B {
    static function withFunarg(f:Void->Void):Void{
         //HERE
    }
    public static function main(){
         var a = new A();
         withFunarg(a.f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot and there is no way to retrieve `this`. But it seems to me like an anti-pattern trying to do that. If you want the method and the container you can define a typedef:

```
typedef F = {
  f : Void -> Void
}
```

Now you have the method and the container.

Comment: It's just different in languages like C or ECMAScript - functions have implicit argument, so you have separate function and owner.

Answer (score 1):

Haxe doesn't offer a cross-platform way to do that and it is generally not recomended.

But if you ultimately need this feature, you can use some platform-specific ways.

For example on js the following will work(at least on current haxe dev version):

```
  static function getThis(f:Dynamic):Dynamic{
    return (f.scope && f.method) ? f.scope : null;
  }
```

It will return the object if the function is a method and a null otherwise. Result on calling on non-function is unspecified.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the implicit `this' argument of a method, you have to make it explicit, like this

```
static function withMethodFunarg(o:{}, f:{}->Void):Void{
    //HERE you have both object and function on this object
    trace(o);
    f(o);
}

public static function main(){
     var a = new A();
     withMethodFunarg(a,function(a){a.f()});
}
```

Which is, actually, pretty straight-forward: function is a function, no implicits, method caller is a method caller.